# PHP strange picture file name

Tags: php

I have this function in php:

```
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    /* Poster */
    if (!file_exists('./img/'.$item->orignaziv.' ('.$item->godina.').jpg')) {

      $remote_file = $item->plakat;
      $new_width = 117;
      $new_height = 168;
      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($remote_file);
      $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_file);
      imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
      imagejpeg($image_p, './img/'.ucfirst($item->orignaziv).' ('.$item->godina.').jpg', 100);
      imagedestroy($image_p);
    }
```

And if poster name is for example:

```
Poster's Name
```

I get when picture is saved to my hdd this:

```
Posterâ€™s Name
```

How to do character encoding to be displayed picture file name like in original with '?

Comment: check that **mbstring** extension is enable in your **php.ini** file.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to let external sources affect your filenames directly. Imagine slightly different code and the poster's name being `Poster/../whatever.php`?

Comment: echo extension_loaded('mbstring'); returns 1 so it is enabled...i need to grab some xml file and there is some image names in multiple names..so using one name for multiple images is not ok...i think php did not decode right ' character so i im searching for solution...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by converting special character ' into html entitles and then string replace with none so that is removed...i know i should use more easy and clean code like preg_replace_all to remove all non standard characters but this works...

```
$item->orignaziv = str_replace('&rsquo;', '', mb_convert_encoding($item->orignaziv, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));
```

This way if i put '' it gets removed all special character but if i put '\'' it gets filename ' in name so it all works.